# iOS storyboards - UINavigationBar not appearing when I add it

Tags: ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I added a UINavigationBar to a detail controller scene, but when I run my app the UINavigationBar does not appear. Why is it doing this ? I have the custom class set to the controller I want it too, but its not appearing, here is a screenshot.

[image]

but when I run this app, I dont see the "Title" bar or anything.

Comment: How are you moving to the detail scene, in code, or with a segue. If in code, post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add constraints select your navigation bar and click in the icon as in the picture.

[image]

uncheck "constrain to margins" as you want the navigation bar to snap in the boards of the screen, select the up and left red dots lines and add the value 0 to the drop boxes, meaning 0 pixels from the left and top of the screen.
Select Update frames and click in add constraints.

I can see in your screenshot you have other screen with problems (red icon next to the view controller) you should also fix that, click in the icon for more details about the error/warning

Comment: Fallow this apple document to debug your view, have a look if your navigation bar is lost somewhere or is actually not been created.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but try this,

Select the detail view and go to the xCode menu and select editor->Embed in-> Navigation Controller.

I hope it helps

Comment: No that didnt do anything...even when I add a simple label it does not appear.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more? Do you see the first screen with the navigation controller but when it go to the details page the navigation controller is not there anymore? Is that what is happening?

Comment: What is happening is, I am adding a UINavigationBar to my Detail Controller Scene, When I run my app the UINavigationBar is not there at all even though I added it the scene,

Answer (score 0):

Add constraints to your navigation bar. However, IcaroNZ suggested the best way for navigation

Comment: How do I add constraints ?